# Cursor is not working in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I insert some date in my local db(sqlite).But when i want to select this data,cursor is not build xml and skip this block.I have one row in my sqlite.Do you have any idea?

This is my code:`

```
public void insertMessages(int msgid,String msgdesc, String date, int createdby,int to) {
    SQLiteDatabase myDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();

            String query = "INSERT INTO Messages (_id,msgdesc,date,createdby,sendto) "+
                           " VALUES ("+msgid+",'"+msgdesc+"','"+date+"',"+createdby+","+to+")";
            SQLiteStatement st = myDatabase.compileStatement(query);

    try {
        st.execute();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    myDatabase.close();
    Log.i("insert","insert Messages completed");
}




public String getMessages(int to) {
        SQLiteDatabase myDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String xml = null;

        try {

            String query = "SELECT _id,msgdesc,date,createdby,sendto from Messages Where sendto="+to+"";    
            Cursor cs = myDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);

            xml = "<messagelist>";
            *****if (cs.moveToFirst()) {*****
                do {
                    xml += "<messages>";
                    xml += "<msgid>"+cs.getInt(cs.getColumnIndex("_id"))+"</msgid>";
                    xml += "<msgdesc>"+cs.getString(cs.getColumnIndex("msgdesc"))+"</msgdesc>";
                    xml += "<date>"+cs.getString(cs.getColumnIndex("date"))+"</date>";
                    xml += "<createdby>"+cs.getInt(cs.getColumnIndex("createdby"))+"</createdby>";
                    xml += "<to>"+cs.getInt(cs.getColumnIndex("sendto"))+"</to>";
                    xml += "</messages>";
                } while (cs.moveToNext());
            }
            xml += "</messagelist>";
            cs.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        myDatabase.close();


        Log.i("select","select completed");
        return xml;
    }`
```

Comment: Do you get any error message ?

Comment: try to change sendto="+to+""  >>  sendto='"+to+"'" add ' in comparing strings

Comment: No ı havent got error message.It is execute query get this row    xml = "<messagelist>"; after the if skip this block   xml += "</messagelist>"; cs.close(); so it is not prepare xml

Comment: @DuyguK : check num of row in Cursor using `cs.getCount();`

Comment: ow 0.What is the problem.It was seen insert is working ? I edit my question

Comment: @DuyguK : problem solved or not?

Comment: I dont understand.Select seen ok but not inserted data.Because cs.Count is 0.Can you see my insert class please? Why is not insert

Comment: @DuyguK : plz see this example http://simonwdixon.wordpress.com/2011/08/16/android-sqllite-tip-2-use-compiled-sql-statements/

Answer (score 1):

```
"SELECT _id,msgdesc,date,createdby,sendto from Messages Where sendto="+to+"";
```

You must delimit string constants with single quotes.  Try this

```
"SELECT _id,msgdesc,date,createdby,sendto from Messages Where sendto = '" + to + "'";
```

Even better would be to use parameterised queries.

http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/t/83.aspx

Comment: but to is integer not string?